# How would you rewrite this mysql syntax using Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
ifnull(min(r.sold_date),IF('xxx' in ('xx','xxx','xxxx') and r.refill_status = 'Sold',r.refill_request_date,p.latest_sold_date)) as sold_date
```

The part where I am having the most trouble is the `min(r.sold_date)`.  I need sold_date as part of the output so I can't put it in the main select statement because you can't aggregate a min, max, etc in your group by

Comment: There needs to be more context. Is this in a SELENT or JOIN ON or WHERE clause?

Answer (score 0):

you you have

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 100 |
| 2 | 10 | 101 |
| 3 | 20 | 102 |
| 4 | 20 | 103 |

and you want the `min(c)` for all same `b` but you also want to get all 4 four rows out. Thus if you want

| a | b | c | min_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 100 | 100 |
| 2 | 10 | 101 | 100 |
| 3 | 20 | 102 | 102 |
| 4 | 20 | 103 | 102 |

Then you want the WINDOW FUCNTION version of MIN which looks like:

```
SELECT 
    a,
    b,
    c,
    MIN(c) OVER (partition by b) as min_c
FROM VALUES 
(1,10,100),
    (2,10,101),
    (3,20,102),
    (4,20,103) 
    v(a,b,c);
```